# Wait to read a csv file until the file is created

Tags: python, time, progress-bar, streamlit

I am creating an app in Streamlit. It has a function which reads a .csv file through Pandas to create further visualizations. However, the .csv file which it reads is created by another python program and outside the Streamlit app python program.

How can I keep the function to wait to execute or show a progress bar until the file is created by that another program. I exactly don't know how much time it would cost to create the .csv file, so I could not add a function like time.sleep() maybe.

Let me know if you have any suggestion.

Best,

Debayan

Comment: The whole concept of a progress bar implies that you know (roughly) how long the operation will take.  But you said you _don't_ know how long it takes to create the csv.  So I don't see how you can possibly make a reasonable progress bar...

Comment: Put that csv file in another folder say csvfolder. Now in streamlit app, scan the csvfolder. If there is csv file there, its time to read it. The other program that generates the csv should only send the csv file to csvfolder once it is done writing that csv. You can profile this program how long it would take to create a csv. You can create a loop on your streamlit app, to wait for the csv file in the csv folder. To avoid infinite loop, limit your loop based on the time the other program generates the csv.